# Начало пути в Computer Science

Tags: книги

Решил изучать CS и в одном списке литературы увидел книгу
Harold Abelson - Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs
Но там ведь все примеры и т.д написаны на лиспе. Это меня смутило. Хотел бы знать, продолжить ее чтение или это не актуально?

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ

Comment: Более чем актуально (для развития головы, конечно)

Comment: Если чтение исходных текстов лиспа не вызывает идиосинхрозию, то можно продолжить портить карму чтением этой книги :)

Comment: Спасибо за советы, решил все же дочитать. Не зря же везде советуют, да и в комментариях здесь тоже фраза "для развития головы" - звучит убедительно)